# x11 GNOME theme - look and feel of Apple OS X

Tags: linux, macos, gnome, xorg, themes

I'm using GNOME that came w/:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Scientific Linux release 6.1 (Carbon)
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Desktop]$
```

and I was wondering if I can make Apple OS X look and feel on my X11, my goal isn't just a theme but also some sort of dock launcher that would act like the one that comes with OS X.

Comment: The answer to the question is *yes*. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: You can find many themes for Gnome, Gnome-Shell, GDM,... at gnome-look.org

Comment: @EthanLeroy I'm also looking for dock launcher

Comment: There are plenty of dock launchers for GNOME, I'm sure you find lots if you just do a little bit of research. (Gnome-Do, Docky, ...)

Comment: @slhck i'll try those dock launchers too, seems cool! (thanks for sharing)

Comment: I used docky when I was running ubuntu from the 10.10 release and loved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this is what you're looking for](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Macbuntu?content=129021).

Even when it's called Macbuntu, it works for GNOME 2, the one bundled with this version of Scientific Linux.

Comment: I'm going give this a try...